# How can my Perl script determine whether an Excel file is in XLS or XLSX format?

Tags: perl, excel, zip, file-format

I have a Perl script that reads data from an Excel (`xls`) binary file.  But the client that sends us these files has started sending us `XLSX` format files at times.  I've updated the script to be able to read those as well.  However, the client sometimes likes to name the `XLSX` files with an `.xls` extension, which currently confuses the heck outta my script since it uses the file name to determine which file type it is.

An `XLSX` file is a zip file that contains XML stuff.  Is there a simple way for my script to look at the file and tell whether it's a zip file or not?  If so, I can make my script go by that instead of just the file name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

.xlsx files have the first 2 bytes as 'PK', so a simple open and examination of the first 2 characters will do.

Comment: To be more specific, the first 4 bytes are `"PK\003\004"`.

Comment: While that's probably true for all .xlsx files produced by particular applications, the ZIP file format does not require that -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_file#Structure .

Comment: Yes!  This is what I was hoping for; a quick 'n easy way to check a file, preferably without having to use yet another module.  Thanks!

Comment: Which is `50 4b` in hex.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is possible by checking [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files).

There are quite a few modules in Perl for checking [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files) in a file.

An example using [File::LibMagic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aLibMagic):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::LibMagic;

my $lm = File::LibMagic->new();

if ( $lm->checktype_filename($filename) eq 'application/zip; charset=binary' ) {
    # XLSX format
}
elsif ( $lm->checktype_filename($filename) eq 'application/vnd.ms-office; charset=binary' ) {
    # XLS format
}
```

Another example, using [File::Type](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aType):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Type;

my $ft = File::Type->new();

if ( $ft->mime_type($file) eq 'application/zip' ) {
    # XLSX format
}
else {
    # probably XLS format
}
```

Comment: File::Type is a rather large module.  Since you're only interested in one filetype, I'd probably copy the test from there.  It's just checking to see if the first 4 bytes of the file are `"PK\003\004"`.

Comment: +1 for libmagic. The next release will contain many improvements for zip-derived file types, see [mailing list archive](http://mx.gw.com/pipermail/file/2010/thread.html).

Answer (score 6):

Edit: Archive::Zip is a better

```
solution
 # Read a Zip file
   my $somezip = Archive::Zip->new();
   unless ( $somezip->read( 'someZip.zip' ) == AZ_OK ) {
       die 'read error';
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't work -- this uses the filename suffix to determine the file type, see http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Archive-Extract-0.46/lib/Archive/Extract.pm .  I upvoted this, but it's too late and I can't remove my vote.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`File::Type`](http://search.cpan.org/~pmison/File-Type-0.22/lib/File/Type.pm):

```
my $file = "foo.zip";
my $filetype = File::Type->new( );

if( $filetype->mime_type( $file ) eq 'application/zip' ) {
  # File is a zip archive.
  ...
}
```

I just tested it with a `.xlsx` file, and the `mime_type()` returned `application/zip`. Similarly, for a `.xls` file the `mime_type()` is `application/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the xls file by checking the first bytes of the file for Excel headers.

A list of valid older Excel headers can be gotten from here (unless you know exact version of their Excel, check for all applicable possibilities):

http://toorcon.techpathways.com/uploads/headersig.txt

---

Zip headers are described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#File_headers
but i'm not sure if .xlsx files have the same headers.

File::Type's logic seems to be "PK\003\004" as the file header to decide on zip files... but I'm not certain if that logic would work as far as .xlsx, not having a file to test.

Answer (score -1):

```
The-Evil-MacBook:~ ivucica$ file --mime-type --brief file.zip 
application/zip
```

Hence, probably comparing

```
`file --mime-type --brief $filename`
```

with `application/zip`would do the trick of detecting zips. Of course, you need to have `file` installed which is quite usual on UNIX systems. I'm afraid I cannot provide Perl example since all knowledge of Perl evaporated from my memory, and I have no examples at hand.

Answer (score -2):

I can't say about Perl, but with the framework I use, .Net, there are a number of libraries available that will manipulate zip files you could use.

Another thing that I've seen people use is the command-line version of WinZip.  It give a return-value that is 0 when a file is unzipped and non-zero when there is an error.

This may not be the best way to do this, but it's a start.